# Need help in using sms code for php

Tags: php, curl, sms, sms-gateway

I need to use send SMS using PHP code. I am using the msg91.com service for sending SMS. I have tried using it but is unable to send SMS. I am using WAMP server and the cURL extension is on.

Can anyone help give me some steps or some idea that how can I do it?

please refer [this site](https://control.msg91.com/apidoc/samplecode/php-sample-code-send-sms.php).

Comment: Curious.  How many messages are you going to be sending?  Have you considered a GPRS modem?

Comment: did it worked i have used same code it ran fine but sms is not received on the phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fill in the blanks

How many messages?

```
<?php

//Your authentication key
$authKey = "YourAuthKey";

//Multiple mobiles numbers separated by comma
$mobileNumber = "9999999";

//Sender ID,While using route4 sender id should be 6 characters long.
$senderId = "102234";

//Your message to send, Add URL encoding here.
$message = urlencode("Test message");

//Define route 
$route = "default";
//Prepare you post parameters
$postData = array(
    'authkey' => $authKey,
    'mobiles' => $mobileNumber,
    'message' => $message,
    'sender' => $senderId,
    'route' => $route
);

//API URL
$url="https://control.msg91.com/sendhttp.php";

// init the resource
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData
    //,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true
));


//Ignore SSL certificate verification
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);


//get response
$output = curl_exec($ch);

//Print error if any
if(curl_errno($ch))
{
    echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);

echo $output;
?>
```